# Sidebar doesn't display the complete menu tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, menu, sidebar

I'm developing a react app and I'm facing an issue. I have a structure as follows:

- Unifo

  - Admin

    - Region
    - Country
  - Servers

My problem is that the sidebar will only display until the admin/servers level. However, when logging, it displays the complete tree in the console (including region and country) which makes me think that the logic is correct!

[console.log print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0LAQ.png)

**Sidebaritem.tsx**

```
export interface SidebarItemProps {
    title: string;
    href: string;
    selected?: boolean;
    onListItemClick?: () => void;
}

export const SidebarItem = (props: SidebarItemProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { title, href, selected, onListItemClick } = props;

    return (
        <RouterLink className={classes.link} to={href}>
            <ListItem button selected={selected} onClick={onListItemClick}>
                <ListItemText primary={title} />
            </ListItem>
        </RouterLink> 
    );
};

export interface ExpandableSidebarItemProps {
    title: string;
    icon?: ReactNode;
    collapsed: boolean;
    onExpand?: () => void;
    son?: SidebarItemProps[];
}

export const ExpandableSidebarItem = (props: ExpandableSidebarItemProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { title, icon, son, collapsed, onExpand } = props;

    return (
        < >
            <ListItem button onClick={onExpand}>
                {icon && <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>}
                <ListItemText primary={title} />
                {collapsed ? <ExpandMoreIcon/> : <ExpandLessIcon/>}
            </ListItem>
            <Collapse in={!collapsed}>
                <List>
                    {son.map((c, index) => (
                        <RouterLink key={index} className={classes.link} to={c.href}>
                            <ListItem 
                                className={classes.nestedItem} 
                                button 
                                selected={c.selected}
                                onClick={c.onListItemClick}>
                                <ListItemText primary={c.title} />
                            </ListItem>
                        </RouterLink>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </Collapse>
        </>
    );
};
```

**SideBar.tsx**

```
const drawerWidth = 217;
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    drawer: {
        [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0
        }
    },
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
            top: 64,
            height: "calc(100% - 64px)"
        }
    },
    avatarBox: {
        marginLeft: "25px",
        marginRight:"20px"
    },
    profileDiv:{
        display:"flex",
        marginBottom: "50px",
        marginTop:"25px",
        alignItems: "center"

    }
}));

const Sidebar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useLocalization();

    const selectedKey = useHistoryListener();

    const modules = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.navigation.modules);
    const drawerOpen = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.navigation.drawerOpen);

    const getViewFromModule = (module: Module): View => ({
        key: module.key,
        path: module.path,
        title: module.title,
        cleanStateAction: module.cleanStateAction
    });

    const getSideBarItemFromModule = (module: Module): SidebarItemProps => ({
        title: module.title(),
        href: module.path,
        selected: module.key === selectedKey,
        onListItemClick: () => dispatch(openView(getViewFromModule(module)))
    });

    const drawerContent = (
        <>
            <div  className={classes.profileDiv}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatarBox}>
                    FS
                </Avatar>
                <Typography variant="h5">
                    Francisco
                </Typography>
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {modules.map(module => (
                    <Fragment key={module.key}>
                        {module.section && <SidebarSection title={module.section()} />}
                        {module.subModules?.length ? (
                            <ExpandableSidebarItem
                                title={module.title()}
                                collapsed={module.collapsed ?? false}
                                onExpand={() => module.collapsed ? dispatch(expandModule(module.key)) : dispatch(collapseModule(module.key))}
                                son={module.subModules.map(subModule => getSideBarItemFromModule(subModule))} />
                        ) : (
                            <SidebarItem
                                title={module.title()}
                                href={module.path}
                                selected={module.key === selectedKey}
                                onListItemClick={() => dispatch(openView(getViewFromModule(module)))} />
                        )}
                    </Fragment>
                ))}
                
            </List>
        </>
    );

    return (
        <nav className={classes.drawer}>
            <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
                <Drawer
                    classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
                    variant="permanent"
                    anchor="left">
                    {drawerContent}
                </Drawer>
            </Hidden>
            <Hidden mdUp implementation="css">
                <Drawer
                    classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
                    variant="temporary"
                    anchor="left"
                    ModalProps={{ keepMounted: true }}
                    open={drawerOpen}
                    onClose={() => dispatch(closeDrawer())}>
                    {drawerContent}
                </Drawer>
            </Hidden>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

**modules.ts**

```
export const modules: Module[] = [
    {
        key: 1,
        title: labels.unifo,
        path: paths.UNIFO,
        subModules: [
            {
                key: 2,
                title: labels.server_title,
                path: paths.MANAGE_SERVERS,
                component: ServerManageView,
                cleanStateAction: cleanServerState
            },
            {
                key: 3,
                title: labels.administration,
                path: paths.ADMINISTRATION,
                subModules: [
                    {
                        key: 4,
                        title: labels.country_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_COUNTRIES,
                        component: CountryManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanCountryState,
                    
                    },                    
                    {
                        key: 5,
                        title: labels.insignia_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_INSIGNIAS,
                        component: InsigniaManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanInsigniaState
                    },
                    {
                        key: 6,
                        title: labels.fusion_unifo_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_FUSION_UNIFO,
                        component: FusionUnifoManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanFusionUnifoState
                    },
                    {
                        key: 7,
                        title: labels.UAAS_version_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_UAAS_VERSIONS,
                        component: UAASVersionManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanUAASVersionState
                    },
                    {
                        key: 8,
                        title: labels.unifo_version_os_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_UNIFO_VERSION_OS,
                        component: UnifoVersionOSManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanUnifoVersionOSState
                    },
                    {
                        key: 9,
                        title: labels.unifo_version_pos_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_UNIFO_VERSION_POS,
                        component: UnifoVersionPOSManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanUnifoVersionPOSState
                    },
                    {
                        key: 10,
                        title: labels.unifo_version_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_UNIFO_VERSION,
                        component: UnifoVersionManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanUnifoVersionState
                    },
                    {
                        key: 12,
                        title: labels.region_title,
                        path: paths.MANAGE_REGIONS,
                        component: RegionManageView,
                        cleanStateAction: cleanRegionState
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
];



export const getKeyFromPath = (path: string): number => {
    for (let i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
        if (modules[i].path === path)
            return modules[i].key;
        const subModule = modules[i].subModules?.find(subModule => subModule.path === path);
        if (subModule)
            return subModule.key;
    }
    return 0;
};

export const getModuleFromKey = (key: number): Module => {
    if (key <= 0)
        return null;
    for (let i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
        if (modules[i].key === key)
            return modules[i];
        const subModule = modules[i].subModules?.find(subModule => subModule.key === key);
        const subs = modules[i].subModules;
        if (subModule)
            return subModule;
    }
    return null;
};

export const getBreadCrumbs = (key: number): string[] => {
    const result: string[] = ["Home"];
    if (key <= 0)
        return result;
    for (let i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
        if (modules[i].key === key) {
            result.push(modules[i].title());
            break;
        }
        const subModule = modules[i].subModules?.find(subModule => subModule.key === key);
        if (subModule) {
            result.push(modules[i].title());
            result.push(subModule.title());
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Please help.

EDIT: I've changed the children attribute name to `son` but I still get this error in the console:      Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Sidebar displays only the first nested level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69753015/react-sidebar-displays-only-the-first-nested-level)

Comment: It's actually the same problem but no answer @AhmetEmreKılınç

Comment: NOTE you do not have to use `<Fragment></Fragment>`. Instead just use `<></>` . `Fragment` is old... deprecated kinda.

Comment: If you go inti inspect element, can you see the devs of your nested sidebar navs or not?

Comment: Not in the html of the page, only when console logging @Lith

Comment: I assume the issue comes because of `children`. Its a variable passed to a parent component automatically by the React. it takes all child components (example: `<Parent><ChildA /><ChildB /> </Parent>`) nad pass it to `children` prop. You manually set the `children` in the `Sidebar > const drawerContent`. This is not good. In the web you should see an error for that in the console. Regardless if you see it ro not - should not do that. Change the variable name rom `children` to something else, plz, to confirm that is not the issue as I expect it is.

Comment: @Lith thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the late response. Indeed that error displays on the console even after changing children to  'test' and mapping test on the sub modules, so I'm still kind of struggling.

Comment: The error will be displayed regardless of what variable you give to parameter `children`. The reason is because ReactJs dosent want you to manually set `children` value. Irs generated by ReactJs and used in varios ways. `children` is one of the parameter key words that are pre-registered per all components and should NEVER be invoked manually. You CAN map it, read it or use it in any other way BUT should NEVER set it manually like `children={"test"}`. You NEED to change your parameter name from `children` to something else.

Comment: son={module.subModules.map(subModule => getSideBarItemFromModule(subModule))} />


  {son.map((c, index) => (
                        <RouterLink key={index} className={classes.link} to={c.href}>...


export interface ExpandableSidebarItemProps {
    title: string;
    icon?: ReactNode;
    collapsed: boolean;
    onExpand?: () => void;
    son?: SidebarItemProps[];
}


I've changed the parameter name not the not the value @Lith